# React Native Expo: useEffect and setParams doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo, react-navigation

So I am trying to create a function that will be pass on my setParams so that I can execute whatever is in that function inside my navigator via onPress.

Here's my EditProductsScreen:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const EditProductScreen = props => {

    // Check if you are in edit mode 
    const prodId = props.route.params?.productId;

    const editedProduct = useSelector(state => state.products.userProducts.find(prod => prod.id === prodId));

    const [title, setTitle] = useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.title : '');
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.imageUrl : '');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.description : '');
    

    // In order to submit we need to use this handler
    const submitHandler = useCallback(() => {
       console.log('Submitting!')
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ submit: submitHandler}));
    }, [submitHandler])
```

As you can see here:

```
// In order to submit we need to use this handler
    const submitHandler = useCallback(() => {
       console.log('Submitting!')
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ submit: submitHandler}));
    }, [submitHandler])
```

I am passing this to my setParams then on my navigation:

```
 <AdminNavigator.Screen
                name="EditProduct"
                component={EditProductScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    // so when you navigate wihout passing anything the route.params is undefined
                    // when you access a property if undefined it throws an error
                    const productId = route.params?.productId;
                    const submit = route.params?.submit;
                    return {
                        title: productId ? "Edit Product" : "Add Product",
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='Save'
                                    iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-checkmark' : 'ios-checkmark'}
                                    onPress={submit}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        )
                    };
                }}
            />
        </AdminNavigator.Navigator>
```

I am trying to execute it through `onPress={submit}`. But instead of console.logging the word "Submitting" it freezes the screen and wont move to any screen at all. Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with navigation, its in these lines

```
const submitHandler = React.useCallback(() => {
       console.log('Submitting!')
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
       console.log('Submitting! 121');
       navigation.setParams({ submit: submitHandler});
    }, [])
```

First you should not pass a dependency here if you want the useEffect to run when a component is mounted , the problem is when the sumbitHandler is provided as the dependency it keeps re rendering which causes the useCallback create new submitHandler so it ends up in an infinite loop.
Also there is no need to go through commonactions you can directly set parameter like above.